# Zig 0.8.0 error: values of type '(enum literal)' must be comptime known

Tags: switch-statement, zig

In Zig 0.8.0, When switching over u8 characters to get an enum type, I encountered a strange compiler error from this code:

```
.op_type = switch(c1) {
    '+' => .add, '-' => .sub,
    '*' => .mul, '/' => .div,
    '%' => .mod, '^' => .exp,
    '|' => .bor, '~' => .bxor,
    '&' => .band,
    '<' => if (is_long) .lte else .lt,
    '>' => if (is_long) .gte else .gt,
    '=' => if (is_long) .eq  else .nop,
    '!' => if (is_long) .neq else return TokenError.NotAToken,
    else => unreachable
}
```

The error was:

```
.\lib.zig:137:36: error: values of type '(enum literal)' must be comptime known
                        '<' => if (is_long) .lte else .lt,
                               ^
```

Normally in zig, "`must be comptime known`" messages mean that I have left off a type signature on a runtime value, such as `const x = 3;`. However, there aren't signatures in a switch expression, and the compiler should know what the type is anyway because the field `.op_type` takes an `Op` type enum.

I was able to solve the issue by using a switch statement instead of an expression, which I used to assign a placeholder value. The result is atrocious:

```
var op_type: Op = undefined;
switch(c1) {
    '+' => op_type = .add, '-' => op_type = .sub,
    '*' => op_type = .mul, '/' => op_type = .div,
    '%' => op_type = .mod, '^' => op_type = .exp,
    '|' => op_type = .bor, '~' => op_type = .bxor,
    '&' => op_type = .band,
    '<' => if (is_long) {op_type = .lte;} else {op_type = .lt;},
    '>' => if (is_long) {op_type = .gte;} else {op_type = .gt;},
    '=' => if (is_long) {op_type = .eq ;} else {op_type = .nop;},
    '!' => if (is_long) {op_type = .neq;} else return TokenError.NotAToken,
    else => unreachable
}
...
... {
    ...
    .op_type = op_type
}
```

The reason I'm posting this question is that I don't really understand the problem with the first implementation, and I would like to see if there is a better solution than what I came up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're experiencing is a quirk of enum literals. When you're writing `.sub`, at first that's an enum literal that is yet to be coerced to an actual enum type. Normally this process works transparently but in this case the type system doesn't seem to be able to "reason" through your `if` expressions.

It might be that this will be improved in the self-hosted compiler, but in the meantime the solution is to simply be explicit about the enum type when you encounter this problem.

Here's a simplified version of your code snippet that compiles: https://zig.godbolt.org/z/zeTnf3a67

Comment: I was told that self-hosted does solve the problem indeed. Keep an eye out for when Zig 0.9.0 comes out!

Comment: Thank you! It sort of makes sense that the type of `Op` can't be inferred from `.sub`. In my original example, simply adding the explicit `Op.sub` and so forth solved the problem; however, I only needed it in the `else` branches. Odd. Excited for Zig 0.9.0!